# Download file from Amazon S3 with node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I've got a MEAN stack app and I'm trying to allow users to download files that are stored using Amazon's S3. I'm generating a preSigned URL for the user, but when I go to that URL in Chrome I get the following error message

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

When I query the node app from Postman it generates a supposedly presigned URL with on issues, but evidently it doesn't work. Here is my relevant code:

```
var express=require('express');
var S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/downloadURL', (req,res,next) => {
  const s3 = new S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'us-east-2' // region of my bucket and what it says is expected
  });
  var s3params = {'Bucket': process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME, 'Key': 'folder1/file.pdf'}
  s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3params, function(err, url) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.json(url);
  });
});
```

When queried by postman I get a URL of the following format

https://bucketname.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/folder1/file.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ACCESS_KEY_HERE%2F20180515%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180515T174606Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=89f6b9a6be699fc1e3268bceaf6585d34ed11e077126ba7c634b769f1add4475&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

Comment: Amazon recommends troubleshooting with these steps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-troubleshooting.html

most likely is some sort of config issue

Comment: Are you sure that you have supplied valid credentials (both access key and secret key)? S3 object pre-signing is a local operation and does not pre-validate the credentials you supply afaik. I'd guess that you've supplied mismatched credentials, or incomplete credentials, and the signed URL is invalid.